# Is there a way to get message in Teams and Azure DevOps when someone mentions me in a comment in a Work Item or Pull Request?

Tags: azure-devops

Usually Azure DevOps send the notifications as **Email**:
[image]
but I want

- Get a message in a chat in [Teams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software)
- Get a notification inside the Azure DevOps environment (for example in top bar)

**when someone mentions me** in a comment in a *Work Item* or *Pull Request*.

Is there an extension or special way to having these features?

Comment: Seriously. This hurts my soul that it isn't the default, out-of-the-box behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Azure DevOps you can use webhooks directly to teams, just lookaround for implementation.

GitHub, you can use WebHook and send the message to an ETL, like LogicApp that will send the message to teams, or you can make your own middleware, there are some options to comunicate with teams (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-csharp)

Answer (score 0):

Did you find an answer to this?

I looked into using Power Automate within teams but the only options are:

[image: Power Automate within MS Teams]

It appears all the options with dev ops itself are just for email... not very useful unless you're checking email all day every day (which is not conducive to getting a lot done!)